# GitHub Actions create or update a Git Tag

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Each time I commit to a Pull Request branch I want to tag it like `0.0.0-pr1`
The below action works on initial commit.
But not on subsequent commits I get `Error: Unhandled error: HttpError: Reference already exists`

Is there a create or update Ref API I could use?

```
    env:
      PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}

    steps:

    - name: Create Git tag for PR
      uses: actions/github-script@v4
      with:
        script: |
          github.git.createRef({
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            ref: "refs/tags/0.0.0-pr${{env.PR_NUMBER}}",
            sha: context.sha
          })
```

Comment: There is the [updateRef API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#update-a-reference). Did you try using it?

Comment: Could this be because you are trying to add a tag that already exists (i.e. a tag that was added by a previous run of this action)? Have you consider adding `github.run_id` to the tag?

Comment: Another alternative would be to remove the tag if it already exists first.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Audun's solution:

You can catch the error and perform an updateRef() instead:

```
permissions:
  contents: write

steps:
  - name: ️ Create/update tag
    uses: actions/github-script@v7
    with:
      script: |
        github.rest.git.createRef({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          ref: 'refs/tags/v${{ needs.version.outputs.version }}',
          sha: context.sha
        }).catch(err => {
          if (err.status !== 422) throw err;
          github.rest.git.updateRef({
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            ref: 'tags/v${{ needs.version.outputs.version }}',
            sha: context.sha
          });
        })
```

I also used EndBug/latest-tag for a little while, but it is currently triggering warnings because it is still using an old version of node.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [EndBug/latest-tag GitHub action from Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/latest-tag) that adds **(or updates)** your custom tag:

```
    env:
      PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}

    steps:

      # make sure you checkout first
      - name: "⏬ Check out repository code"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "️ Push tag"
        uses: EndBug/latest-tag@latest
        with:
          # You can change the name of the tag with this input.
          # Default: 'latest'
          tag-name: ${{env.PR_NUMBER}}
      
          # If a description is provided, the action will use it to create an annotated tag. If none is given, the action will create a lightweight tag.
          #description: Description for the tag
```

As you can see, I had an existent tag (`2.0.0-41`) which got overwritten

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: "Tag Releases"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v2
        env:
          CLIENT_PAYLOAD: ${{ toJSON(github.event.client_payload) }}
        with:
          script: |
            const { owner, repo } = context.repo;
            const { sha, releases } = JSON.parse(process.env.CLIENT_PAYLOAD);

            for (const release of releases) {
              const tagName = `${release.module}/${release.newVersion}`;

              let ref = `refs/tags/${tagName}`;
              console.log('Tagging', tagName, 'as', sha);
              await github.git.createRef({ owner, repo, ref, sha });

              const releaseVersion = `${release.newVersion}`;
              const module = `${release.module}`;

                try {
                    ref = "tags/" + module + "/v" + releaseVersion.split(".")[0]
                    console.log('Updating existing tag', ref, 'as', sha);
                    await github.git.updateRef({ owner, repo, ref, sha });
                  }
                catch {
                    ref = "refs/tags/" + module + "/v" + releaseVersion.split(".")[0]
                    console.log('Creating new tag', ref, 'as', sha);
                    await github.git.createRef({ owner, repo, ref, sha });
                  }
              }
```

In this case I have a monorepo which contains several terraform modules and they are versioned as `modulename/SemVer` and also `moduleName/MajorVersion`

console output:

````
Tagging monorepo-release-template/1.0.1 as 42b.....
Updating existing tag tags/monorepo-release-template/v1 as 42b....
```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Below is my GitHub action code to create a tag

```
  - name: Create Tag
    uses: rickstaa/action-create-tag@v1.7.2
    with:
      tag: tag_to_be_created
```

Read more about configuration and possible options at https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-update-tag